# How I can express this mathematically?

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I'm working on a OR project. I have a code which fixes my problem which uses the constraint

> ((a =< b) or (c =< d) or (e =< f)) = True

I need to rewrite this condition as mathematical expression(s)

I tried

> (a-b) * (c-d) * (e-f) =< 0

Which seems to work for most cases but fails when two of them are positive and one of them are negative.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think you need to write this more compactly? Your first condition seems clear to me.

Comment: I need to write down a mathematical model for my code, which got me stuck.

Comment: I don't know exactly why you want this but you could do $\frac{b-a}{|b-a|} + \frac{d-c}{|d-c|} + \frac{f-e}{|f-e|} \neq -3$

Comment: WOW! that was brilliant. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$\max(b-a,d-c,f-e)\ge 0$.

But really, it already was mathematical.

Answer (score 0):

Another way: 
$$ (|a - b| + a - b)(|c - d| + c - d)(|e - f| + e - f) \le 0 $$

Comment: I think you can use $=0$ instead of $\le 0$ if you want